# Как записать результат поиска в массив

Tags: c, массивы, строки

Дана задача: Написать программу, которая для введённой строки 
   выводит самое длинное слово его длину. К задаче есть пояснение Программа должна состоять из функций:

```
- int getMaxWord(char buf[],char word[]) - нахождение слова максимальной длины. 
Слово записывается в массив word, а его длина возвращается из функции
- main().
```

Написал программу , но никак не могу разобраться как записать найденное самое длинное слово в массив word ? Подскажите пожалуйста.Как реализовать решение в согласии с заданием.
Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char s[100];
    int i, id, max, count, len;
    fgets(s,100,stdin);
    len = strlen(s);
    max = 0;
    id = 0;
    count = 0;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
        if (s[i] != ' '){
         count += 1;

}        else {
            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
                id = i - count;

            }
            count = 0;
        }

    if (count > max) {

        max = count;
        id = i - count;

    }
    printf("%d",max);
    max += id;


    for (i=id; i<max; i++)
        putchar(s[i]);


    puts("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы в курсе, что у вас огроменный косяк уже в условии? В функцию передаётся указатель на массив `word[]`, но не указан его размер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Далеко не оптимально, но в абстрактных условиях я бы решал задачу как-то так:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Ну, допустим */
#define SEPARATORS  " \t\r\n;:,.!?\"'"

/* ненавижу CamelCase, sorry */
static int get_longest_word(const char *sentence, char **word)
{
    int max_length = 0;
    char *longest_word = NULL;
    char *dup = strdup(sentence);
    char *token = strtok(dup, SEPARATORS);

    while (token) {
        /* int или всё-таки size_t - вопрос дискуссионный :) */
        int length = strlen(token);
        if( length > max_length ) {
            max_length = length;
            longest_word = token;
        }
        token = strtok( NULL, SEPARATORS);
    }

    /* Перестраховка */
    *word = longest_word ? strdup( longest_word ) : NULL;
    free( dup );
    return max_length;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char sentence[] = "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet";
    char *word = NULL;
    int max_length = get_longest_word(sentence, &word);

    printf("Longest word: \"%s\"\n", word ? word : "NOT FOUND");

    free(word);
    return max_length;
}
```

---

Или:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int get_longest_word(const char *sentence, char **word)
{
    int longest_word_length = 0;
    const char *longest_word = NULL;

    while (*sentence ) {

        while( *sentence && !isalpha(*sentence)) ++sentence;
        const char *tmp_word = sentence;
        while( *sentence && isalpha(*sentence)) ++sentence;
        if( longest_word_length < sentence - tmp_word )
        {
            longest_word = tmp_word;
            longest_word_length = sentence - tmp_word;
        }
    }

    if( longest_word_length )
    {
        *word = malloc( longest_word_length + 1 );
        memcpy( *word, longest_word, longest_word_length );
        (*word)[longest_word_length] = 0;
    }
    return longest_word_length;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое , но хотелось бы узнать как реализовать в моем коде и поместить результат в массив)

Comment: @Andrey97, вот чесслово - откровенно не хочется разбираться как править ваш код. Его проще переписать с нуля. Ну вот, добавил ещё вариант, чуть ближе к исходному.